# MySQL Show actual events

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have these tables.

**Table course**

```
IDCourse   |   Description   |...
1          |   php           |...
2          |   MYSQL         |...
```

**Table modules**

```
IDModule   |  Description  | startDate  |  endDate
1          |  introduction | 2014-02-02 | 2014-02-25
2          |  oop          | 2014-02-26 | 2014-03-01
...
99         | sql suntax    | 2014-11-11 | 2014-12-12
```

**Table CourseHasModul**

```
IDCourse  |  IdModule
1         |  1
1         |  2
...       |  ...
2         |  99
```

I 'm trying to get all courses today have some active module. I´m trying this query  but don't work( i dont get de spected result), any idea?

```
SELECT * FROM course
INNER JOIN CourseHasModul ON CourseHasModul.IDCourse = course.IDCourse 
INNER JOIN modules ON modules.IDModule =CourseHasModul.IdModule
WHERE (modules.startDate  <= CURDATE( ) AND modules.endDate<= CURDATE( ) )
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't think this is the problem, but `modul.datainici` and `modul.datafi` are not the column you specified in the model.

Comment: @theLibertine He obviously translated to English in one place, but not the other.

Comment: Also change this line WHERE (modul.datainici <= CURDATE( ) AND modul.datafi >= CURDATE( ) ) to WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN modules.StartDate AND modules.EndDate

Comment: Your query looks reasonable.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: What results are you expecting, and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want courses with an active module, I would go for an `exists`:

```
select c.*
from course c
where exists (select 1
              from CourseHasModul chm join
                   Modules m
                   on chm.IdModule = m.IdModule
              where chm.IDCourse = c.IDCourse and
                    m.datainici <= CURDATE( ) AND m.datafi >= CURDATE( )
             );
```

However, this query should return results similar to your query (albeit with no duplicates for courses that have multiple active modules).

Answer (score 0):

you query seems fine, i think the problem is your where condition. you have to use "OR" instead of "AND" and if i were you i would write the query like the following, it is better always obey the hierarchy of the joins:

```
select course.* from modules 
left join CourseHasModul on modules.IDModule = CourseHasModul.IdModule
left join CourseHasModul.IDCourse = IDCourse on course.IDCourse
where (modules.datainici <= CURDATE() OR modules.datafi >= CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
SELECT * ,MIN(modules.startDate) AS STARTDATE,MAX(modules.endDate) AS ENDDATE
FROM course
INNER JOIN course_has_modules ON course_has_modules.IDCourse = course.IDCourse
INNER JOIN modules ON modules.IDModule = course_has_modules.IDModule

GROUP BY  course.idcourse
HAVING (CURDATE()>=STARTDATE AND CURDATE()<=ENDDATE)
```